# ERROR in [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "..\.eslintrc.json » eslint-config-react-app

Tags: npm, eslint, package.json

I got this error as follows:
`ERROR in [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "..\.eslintrc.json » eslint-config-react-app » G:\client-side\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » G:\client-side\frontend\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".`

where my package.json, and eslint configuration file as follow

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@html-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^0.19.0",
    "@html-eslint/parser": "^0.19.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-security": "^1.7.1",
    "stylelint": "^15.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^34.0.0"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "security",
    "@html-eslint"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "plugin:security/recommended"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "parser": "@html-eslint/parser",
      "extends": "plugin:@html-eslint/recommended"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to unistall and install the devDependencies and clear cache to avoid the version conflicts